# How does unsigned short int differs from unsigned int

Tags: c, unsigned, short

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
    unsigned  short int  x=-10;
    short int y=-10;
    unsigned int z=-10000000;
    int m=-10000000;

    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d m=%d",x,y,z,m);
    return 0;
 }
```

output=`x=65526 y=-10 z=-10000000 m=-10000000`

My query is How `unsigned short int`differ from `unsigned int` in the scenario of data holding. i.e   `x=65526 where as z=-10000000 why x is not equal -10 where as z can hold any data` As short is 2 byte so `twos complement -10 is 65526` but why not same in `case` of `z`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812022/what-is-a-difference-between-unsigned-int-and-signed-int-in-c

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned short int)` and `sizeof(unsigned int)`

Answer (score 4):

When `unsigned  short int  x=-10;` occurs, `x`, being unsigned, gets a modulo or "wrapped" value of `65526`  (OP sizeof(short) is 2).  Something like `x = power(256,sizeof(unsigned short)) - 10`.

When `x` is printed, it is passed to `printf()` as an `int` (variadic promotion).  OP's sizeof(int) is 4, so the 65526 fits in `int`.  Then `printf()` sees a `%d` and prints "65526".

`z` Has a similar story, but sizeof(z) is 4. and gets initialized `z = power(256,sizeof(unsigned)) - 10`.

Your `printf()` is using the `%d` specifier for `unsigned`.  OP should use `%u`.

```
printf("x=%u y=%d z=%u m=%d",x,y,z,m);
```

---

`unsigned short int` is guaranteed to cover at *least* the range 0 to 65535.

`unsigned int` is guaranteed to cover at *least* the range  of `unsigned short int`.  It *may* cover a wider range.

`unsigned int` is usually the native size the processor best uses - typically fastest.

As `unsigned short int` is, in some implementations, smaller than `unsigned int`.  It is preferred for space saving with large arrays.